# Tap on Picture in MMS and a different picture opens up?

Tags: applications, instant-messaging

I will receive a picture in an MMS on my Lg Thin Q.  When I tap on the picture to enlarge it a completely different picture associated to the person who sent this one opens up.  Any suggestions on how to correct this?

Answer (score 2):

It is a known bug with the MMS in SOME LG smartphones where the older version of “Messages” app is installed. Previously deleted MMS picture shows up in newest incoming MMS message instead of the intended image due to this bug.

You can fix it by updating the "Messages" app to the latest version.

Source: https://www.lg.com/ca_en/support/product-help/CT30014940-20150929584034